# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: backtype/storm/spout/MultiScheme

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm, clj-kafka

I am a trying to integrate Storm with Kafka. I am running a Storm topology using `KafkaSpout`. This is the basic word-count topology. I am using Apache Kafka as the source and storm for processing the data. While submitting the topology I am facing these issues. I am very new to Kafka and Storm. Please suggest me the changes I need to do in the following code.

This is my code:

```
public class TopologyMain {

private static final String SENTENCE_SPOUT_ID = "kafka-sentence-spout";
  private static final String WORD_NORMALIZER = "word-normalizer";
  private static final String WORD_COUNTER = "word-counter";
  private static final String TOPOLOGY_NAME = "kafka-word-count-topology";  


  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, AlreadyAliveException, InvalidTopologyException {

      int numSpoutExecutors = 1;

      KafkaSpout kspout = buildKafkaSentenceSpout();
        WordNormalizer normalizeBolt = new WordNormalizer();
        WordCounter countBolt = new WordCounter();



    //Topology definition
    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

    builder.setSpout(SENTENCE_SPOUT_ID, kspout, numSpoutExecutors);
    builder.setBolt(WORD_NORMALIZER, new WordNormalizer()).shuffleGrouping(SENTENCE_SPOUT_ID);
    builder.setBolt(WORD_COUNTER, new WordCounter(),1).fieldsGrouping(WORD_NORMALIZER, new Fields("word"));

    //Configuration
    Config conf = new Config();
    //System.setProperty("storm.jar", "/home/raremile/.m2/repository/org/apache/storm/storm-core/0.9.3/storm-core-0.9.3.jar");
    StormSubmitter.submitTopology(TOPOLOGY_NAME, conf, builder.createTopology());
    conf.setDebug(false);

}

  private static KafkaSpout buildKafkaSentenceSpout() {
        String zkHostPort = "localhost:2181";
        String topic = "sentences";

        String zkRoot = "/acking-kafka-sentence-spout";
        String zkSpoutId = "acking-sentence-spout";
        ZkHosts zkHosts = new ZkHosts(zkHostPort);

        SpoutConfig spoutCfg = new SpoutConfig(zkHosts, topic, zkRoot, zkSpoutId);
        KafkaSpout kafkaSpout = new KafkaSpout(spoutCfg);
        return kafkaSpout;
      }
}
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: backtype/storm/spout/MultiScheme
at TopologyMain.buildKafkaSentenceSpout(TopologyMain.java:57)
at TopologyMain.main(TopologyMain.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: backtype.storm.spout.MultiScheme
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 2 more
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder.setBolt(Ljava/lang/String;Lbacktype/storm/topology/IBasicBolt;Ljava/lang/Integer;)Lbacktype/storm/topology/BoltDeclarer;

Comment: I am able to solve the problem mentioned but now i am facing this issue.

Any Suggestions guys !!

Comment: If you've solved one problem and now have a new one, I'd recommend that you create a new question associated with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you miss the `storm-core` jar in your classpath. Download and add it.

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem. But i am getting a different error now.

SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/raremile/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.5.8/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/raremile/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.0.6/logback-classic-1.0.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.

Comment: SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
SLF4J: The requested version 1.5.8 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6, 1.7]SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Found multiple defaults.yaml resources
 at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.findAndReadConfigFile(Utils.java:106)
 at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.readDefaultConfig(Utils.java:126)
 at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.readStormConfig(Utils.java:146)
 at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter

Comment: @kumarriteshranjansinha Looks like you miss the slf4j or log4j or one ob the bridges in your classpath.