# How to include dependencies with Maven in Storm topology jar for cluster deployment?

Tags: java, docker, maven, jar, apache-storm

I'm trying to deploy a Storm topology to a local standalone cluster. I'll include links to my project's [Github repo](https://github.com/pi-prescott/storm-streaming) so you can see my code...

I have got a [simple Storm topology](https://github.com/pi-prescott/storm-streaming/blob/master/example/java/Topology.java) running in local mode, which I have [tweaked to deploy](https://github.com/pi-prescott/storm-streaming/blob/master/cluster-example/java/Topology.java) to a Dockerized cluster ([simple configuration](https://github.com/pi-prescott/storm-streaming/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) based on the [recommended instructions](https://hub.docker.com/_/storm)).

However, when I try to get it running, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: backtype/storm/topology/IRichSpout
```

It seemed from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30366277/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-backtype-storm-spout) that I just need to include `storm-core` as a dependency in my Maven project when building the `topology.jar`.

So I [adjusted my `pom.xml`](https://github.com/pi-prescott/storm-streaming/blob/master/cluster-example/working_pom.xml) file (I'm not using Eclipse or any IDE, I'm just running Maven from the command line) to include `storm-core` as a dependency, and to include the `maven-assembly-plugin` to package the `jar-with-dependencies`. But now when I try to run the cluster I get an error saying:

```
...
java.io.IOException: Found multiple defaults.yaml resources. You're probably bundling the Storm jars with your topology jar
...
```

So what exactly should I be including as a bundled dependency? And what lines of code do I need to add to/remove from my `pom.xml` to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I have got it working.

The problem was that the Storm dependencies on the Docker cluster were filed under `org.apache.storm`, whereas the local build was using `backtype.storm`. [Changing the references](https://github.com/pi-prescott/storm-streaming/commit/58967111caff44e2f42c46e22f1549bfa6bebee3) to `org.apache.storm` seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the "provided" scope in the storm dependency on the pom.xml file.

Comment: When I do this, I get the NoClassDefFoundError. You can see the `pom.xml` file [here](https://github.com/pi-prescott/storm-streaming/blob/master/cluster-example/working_pom.xml)

Comment: It seems that maven cannot find the source files. Can you add the source directory tag into the build part of the pom file? @PeterPrescott

Comment: Ah, I've fixed it, see my answer.

Comment: Oh, OK! great :D